# Sensenet: Check Out Documents on Upload

Tags: sensenet

When a user upload a document to a document library is possible to this documents automatically remain in the "Check Out" state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the /Root/System/SystemPlugins/Portlets/IntraUploadDialog.ascx. There's a huge Javascript to handle the upload process. You can add additional functionality after upload in the fileupload's done branch.

```
 $('#sn-upload-fileupload').fileupload({
        ...
        done: function (e, data) {
                        inProgress = false;
                        var json = (data.jqXHR.responseText) ? jQuery.parseJSON(data.jqXHR.responseText) : data.result;
                        $('.sn-upload-bar', data.context).addClass('sn-upload-uploadedbar');

                        var filename = json.Name;
                        var url = json.Url;
                        $('.sn-upload-filetitle', data.context).html('<a href="' + url + '">' + filename + '</a>');

                        SN.Upload.uploadFinished(data.formData.ChunkToken);

                       **//call an action or add custom functionality**

                    }
    });
```

There are built-in odata actions in Sense/Net with which you can call actions trough ajax and there's an action for checking-out content.

http://wiki.sensenet.com/Built-in_OData_actions_and_functions#Check_out_action_-_from_version_6.3